# What does "defend a lawsuit" mean?

Tags: phrases, verbs

> The planters sued hundreds of peasants for breaking their indigo
> contracts, with over seventeen thousand rupees being spent defending
> these lawsuits.

([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indigo_revolt))

Does the above sentence mean that the peasants spent 17,000 rupees "defending" those lawsuits, or does it mean that the planters spent 17,000 "defending those lawsuits"?

Comment: The person who _is sued_ (the peasants) has to defend the suit.

Comment: Though it is a hair ambiguous.

Comment: Seems you defend yourself against a lawsuit. Defending a lawsuit sounds like you are standing up **for** the lawsuit, not against it.

Comment: The legal system in India must be incredibly cheap, if the legal bill for hundreds of peasants is only 17,000 rupees (157.91 Pound sterling, according to Google! :)

Comment: @YosefBaskin: Not really - you ***pursue*** the lawsuit if you're on the ***prosecuting*** side. We'd normally expect *defend **against***, but the primary disambiguator is the word "defend".

Comment: Still stuck on Elton John's lyric "your love **protects** my fears" (I Need You to Turn To). I'd prefer protection from fear rather than protecting fears that can defend themselves.

Comment: @FumbleFingers This was a long time ago, so you have to adjust for inflation as well.

Comment: A lawsuit is an action in civil (not criminal) law. At the initial trial level, Its parties are distinguished as the _plaintiff_ (the suing party) and the _defendant_ (the party being sued). Things get messier at the appeals level, where the party that lost at the initial trial and challenges that outcome is denominated the _appellant_ and the party that won at the initial trial is usually called the _respondent_. In practical terms, of course, the respondent on appeal is defending the victory it won at the initial trial, and the appellant is in the position of seeking to overturn it. ...

Comment: ... But in any case, it is poor legal terminology to characterize the plaintiff's expenses in the initial lawsuit as money spent "defending" the lawsuit—whether or not that wording appears in certain accounts of the lawsuit. As FumbleFingers suggests, "pursuing" is a more apt word choice; "prosecuting" is not, however, as that term properly applies only to criminal law. Hence, because trespass is a tort, not a crime, the posting "Trespassers will be prosecuted" is bad law. (Note that the terminology I cite here applies to U.S. law and may not be standard Indian or British legal nomenclature.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the planters who spent money*. They had been sued by peasants and peasant organisations.

From [the Digital South Asia Library](https://dsal.uchicago.edu/books/socialscientist/pager.html?objectid=HN681.S597_60_019.gif) via the University of Chicago: An an article about the indigo wars.

(The Biswases were two brothers, a landlord and a moneylender.)

> The planters would not be daunted or deterred so easily. He sent far more numerous and far more heavily armed forces to rout the villages. These forces wrought great destruction, looting, killing and setting fire everywhere they went. The Biswases at the head of the phalanx sustained the struggle with the help of the lathials hired from Barisal. But the peasants could not hear the pressure for long and the two Biswases fled. Hundreds of peasants were sued for breaking indigo contracts. The Biswases are said to have spent about seventeen thousand rupees towards meeting legal and other expenses.

**it appears that this claim is wrong - it was not the planters who spent 17,000Rps*

Comment: In the 19th century 4.8 Rupees = £1 but the Pound Sterling was on the Gold Standard. As a consequence they shelled out about £5 Million in today's terms.

Answer (score 1):

Certainly in American English the verb **defend** can be used transitively and take **a|the lawsuit** or **a|the suit** as direct object.

*To defend a suit* is to take action to counter the plaintiff's claims against the defendant.

> “Most insurance policies require that suit papers be promptly forwarded to the insurer … to preserve any insurance coverage,” said David Turner, a partner at Schulten Ward Turner & Weiss. “If the suit is covered, the insurer or counsel retained by the insurer will defend the lawsuit.”

https://www.businessnewsdaily.com/8724-small-business-lawsuit-tips.html

**defend** can also be reflexive, e.g. *... defend **themselves** in a suit".